# PostgreSQL casting data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `temperature` containing 5 columns : `centre` `date` `tmpmax` `tmpmin` `rrquot`, `date` `tmpmax` `tmpmin` `rrquot`are stored as `character varying` and I need to convert them to `double precision` in order to manipulate them to calculate some statistics.
I used the following SQL command :

```
ALTER TABLE public.temperature
    ALTER COLUMN "TMPMAX" TYPE double precision
    USING cast("TMPMAX" AS double precision)
```

But it didn't work for the whole table because there are some cells that contains `''` (nothing).

Concerning the date column, is there a way to cast it into date type (data are stored in this format : `YYYYMMDD` ex. `20030122`) with `YYYY-MM-DD` format ex. `1968-01-13`.

Please help in resolving those two problems.

Comment: I did not get why would you convert column you aim to make double precision to date and how it will help fighting empty values, so I suggested the way to fight empty values

Comment: I agree with Vao Tsun. If that is actually a date you should convert it to a `DATE` not a double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use condition in `USING`, like here:

```
t=# create table s106 (i text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into s106 values ('1'),('');
INSERT 0 2
t=# alter table s106 alter COLUMN i type double precision
t-#     USING cast(i AS double precision);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
```

conditional:

```
t=# alter table s106 alter COLUMN i type double precision
    USING cast(case when length(i) < 1 then null else i end AS double precision);
ALTER TABLE
```

Comment: or `cast(nullif(trim(i), '') as double precision)`

Comment: yes - totally agree for my example. I was not sure If op wants to make them NULL, so I suggested full `case` to be clear and flexible

Answer (score 1):

About date type, if I correctly understand, you have dates stored in `character varying` type field, like this: `20030122`, and you need cast values to `date` type, (values become like this: `2003-01-22`)

If so, you can try:

```
ALTER TABLE  temperature
ALTER COLUMN "date" TYPE date
USING  cast("date" as date)
```